# Paytm “networkError” when payment transaction with allinone sdk flutter

Tags: android, flutter, paytm

I have had a go at executing Paytm utilizing both the methodologies ("Standard Checkout" and "Allin one SDK" ) yet my exchange page or Paytm App never opens for the installment and I am getting networkError inside onActivityResult.

I have effectively created checksum and TransactionToken on my hub worker yet on passing the TxnToken to paytm sdk nothing is occurring.

Any idea for what reason is this incident ?

just open paytm from bottom and close .

Answer (score 1):

Add

> bool restrictAppInvoke = true;

And Pass restrictAppInvoke value to Paytm_allineone SDK as Below

```
var response = AllInOneSdk.startTransaction(
          mid, orderId, amount, txnToken, "", isStaging, restrictAppInvoke);
```

Read Documentation As Below:-

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/flutter/?ref=allInOneMerchantIntegration

> restrictAppInvoke is to define app invoke restriction (Only
> Redirection flow when True else AppInovke if Paytm app is installed)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the Paytm app you are using is of staging for the staging environment. You can download the same from Paytm's repo on github

Comment: ok i again try with new update.